# Haskell package persistent-sqlite fails to install in Windows with ld error

Tags: haskell, installation, package, persistent

Trying either one of the following commands in my Win7 system fails.

```
$ stack install persistent-sqlite
$ cabal install persistent-sqlite
```

The error is some rather opaque `ld` related thing.

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring persistent-sqlite-2.2...
Building persistent-sqlite-2.2...
Failed to install persistent-sqlite-2.2
Build log ( C:\Users\TR@FI_02\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\persistent-sqlite-2.2.log ):
Building persistent-sqlite-2.2...
Preprocessing library persistent-sqlite-2.2...
[1 of 2] Compiling Database.Sqlite  ( Database\Sqlite.hs, dist\build\Database\Sqlite.o )
C:\Users\TR@FI_02\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc4324_0\ghc4324_9.ldscript: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no clue what a possible cause might be. Can anyone reproduce this on their system? Where could I start looking to fix this?

**EDIT:**

The log mentioned in the output contains the same information:

```
Building persistent-sqlite-2.2...
Preprocessing library persistent-sqlite-2.2...
[1 of 2] Compiling Database.Sqlite  ( Database\Sqlite.hs, dist\build\Database\Sqlite.o )
C:\Users\TR@FI_02\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc4324_0\ghc4324_9.ldscript: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT:**

This is potentially a rare bug limited to two win7 installations on two PCs I have here. I was not able to consistently reproduce the failure on *every* win7 system.

Comment: Can you post the contents of **C:\Users\TR@FI_02\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\persistent-sqlite-2.2.log**?

Comment: @AlainO'Dea cf. edited question

Comment: Ouch.  That's not great.  The problematic ldscript is probably deleted after failure.  I've used DTrace to pause ghc in situations like this so I can read the offending files.  There may be a way to do something with the Visual Studio Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

That would indicate to me that I should make sure my sql driver is installed and is on my path such that GHC can link to it properly.